# Get the array of strings from the Resource Stream

Tags: delphi, stream

=Getting DATA from Resource is like this:

```
function GetMyRes(resname:string):string;
var
rStream: TResourceStream;
s:string;
begin
rStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, resname, RT_RCDATA);
...
...
result:=s;
End;
```

>

> =Using the DATA

```
Procedure GetReses;
var
myres1:string;
myres2:string;
begin
myres1:=GetMyRes("MYSTRING1");
myres2:=GetMyRes("MYSTRING2");
end;
```

>

> =Putting DATA to Resource is like this:

```
Procedure SaveToResource(Dest:string);
var
s:string;
cbData     : Cardinal;
hDestRes   : THANDLE;
begin
if x=1 then s:='1a' else s:='1b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRING1',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=2 then s:='2a' else s:='2b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRING2',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=3 then s:='3a' else s:='3b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRING3',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=4 then s:='4a' else s:='4b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRING4',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=5 then s:='5a' else s:='5b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRING5',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;
end;
```

>

**The problem here, WHAT if I PUT the Resource like this: (the zero incremented)**

```
Procedure SaveToResource(Dest:string);
var
s:string;
cbData     : Cardinal;
hDestRes   : THANDLE;
begin
if x=1 then s:='1a' else s:='1b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRINGS_ALL',0,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=2 then s:='2a' else s:='2b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRINGS_ALL',1,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=3 then s:='3a' else s:='3b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRINGS_ALL',2,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=4 then s:='4a' else s:='4b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRINGS_ALL',3,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;

if x=5 then s:='5a' else s:='5b';
cbData := Length(s);
hDestRes := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
if hDestRes <> 0 then
begin
UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'MYSTRINGS_ALL',4,PChar(s),cbData);
EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE)
end;
end;
```

**How to get the "MYSTRINGS_ALL" in range 0 to 4?**

>

This is not working, since it only GETS when I put ZER0s in all I named one by one.

```
function GetMyRes(resname:string):string;
var
rStream: TResourceStream;
s:string;
begin
rStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, resname, RT_RCDATA);
...
result:=s;
End;
```

**Whats the correct Function or the way to get all range from 0 to 4 strings?**

>
I think this is the right one, I think so!, please correct if any wrong in the code.

```
function GetMySTRResources(id:integer): string;
 var
   hF,hR:THandle;
   s:PChar;
 begin
  hF:=FindResourceEx(HInstance, RT_RCDATA ,'MYSTRINGS_ALL', id);
  if hF<>0 then begin
    hR:=LoadResource(HInstance, hF) ;
    if hR<>0 then begin
      s:=LockResource(hR) ;
      if Not Assigned(s) then s:='';
      UnlockResource(hR) ;
    end;
    FreeResource(hF) ;
  end;
  Result := s;
 end;
```

Thanks Rob Kennedy

Comment: Resources are not implicitly null-terminated, so you cannot simply assign `s` to `Result`. See how the VCL does it by fetching the resource size. Or make sure to store the null character in the resource to begin with.

Comment: Why not indent your sample source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TResourceStream`, you cannot get all the values you've stored. `TResourceStream` uses `FindResource`, but you need it to use `FindResourceEx` because the numbers you're changing are the *language ID*, and `FindResource` doesn't offer that parameter.

Instead, you can call `FindResourceEx` yourself. That returns a resource handle for you to pass to `LoadResource`. That returns a memory handle; use `LockResource` to get a pointer to the real data. Look in *Classes.pas* in `TResourceStream.Initialize` to see how it's done.

Once you're able to specify the language ID of your resources, then you can load them each separately and arrange them into whatever data structure you want, including an array.